# Ansible loop over the first task output array

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to loop over the first task output in second task. In the first task getting hostname and IP in the array.  In the second task loop over the array print the each item in the array in separate line.

here the code I have so for.

```
- name: Store known hosts of 'all' the hosts in the inventory file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    ssh_known_hosts_command: "ssh-keyscan -T 10"
    ssh_known_hosts_file: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/known_hosts' }}"
    ssh_known_hosts: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

  tasks:

  - name: For each host, find the ip
    shell: 'echo -e "{{ item }}\n`dig +short {{ item }}`"'
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_hosts }}"
    register: ssh_known_host_results
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: print message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout_lines[0] + ' test' }}"
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results }}"
```

in the second task how can I loop over ssh_known_host_results.results  array?

thanks
SR

I am looking for something like this:

```
- name: print message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item+ ' test' }}"
      with_items: "{{outer_item.stdout_lines "    
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results }}"
    loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item
```

when I add to ignore localhost its not giving array item. how can it make return hostname and ip as two array elements?

```
 - name: For each host, find the ip
    shell: 'echo -e "{{ item }}\n`dig +short {{ item }}`"'
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_hosts }}"
    when: not item == 'localhost'
    register: ssh_known_host_results
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: print message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item + ' test' }}"
    with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

Comment: What is the problem? In your code you loop over result of previous task and print first line of every dig result.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, I am looking to add another loop in the second task to iterate sh_known_host_results.results  array item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for dynamic nested loops is not implemented in Ansible.

To iterate over each line, you can flatten the result:

```
- name: print message
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item + ' test' }}"
  with_items: "{{ ssh_known_host_results.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

Comment: when I add "when: not item == 'localhost'" this line its not working any idea?

Comment: there was a copy-paste error in my answer, fixed it. `item` - is a string of stdout here, so you can't compare it to hostname.

Comment: I found it and fixed the problem now I have is when exclude localhost, it not spliting the list array element. look at the code pasted in the last